# find files in specified directory assembly

Tags: file, assembly, x86, dos

I'm trying to make a program that finds files smaller than a certain size. The folders program needs to search in are specified in the beginning. I'm using DOSBOX, TASM and TLINK.
Here's some related code:

```
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
PrepDTA:
mov dx,OFFSET DTA   ; DS:DX points to DTA 
mov ah,1AH      ; function 1Ah - set DTA
int 21h         ; call DOS service
WorkWithFiles:
FindFirst:
mov cx,3fh
mov si, offset DTA
mov ah, 4eh 
mov dx, offset Folder
int 21h
cmp al, 0FFh
je NeraFailu
jmp FileSize
FindNext:
mov si, offset DTA
mov ah, 4fh
mov cx,3fh
mov dx, offset Folder
int 21h
jc NoMoreFiles
jmp FileSize
FileSize:
mov si, offset DTA+26
mov bh, 4
```

So when I run the program, `DTA` after `FindFirst` is set to some nonsence, and on `FindNext` it jumps to `NoMoreFiles`. There are 2 files in the directory I specify, but no matter which directory I specify `DTA` is the same. I tried adding `*.*` in the end, changing the security of files in properties, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to reset `al` before 21/4e? `al` is an argument. http://tippach.business.t-online.de/wdosx/int21api.html

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It is useless in a real program and will teach you nothing if you're learning.